# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse' Even though I'm using Python 3

Tags: python, svg, import, google-analytics, urllib

```
import json
import csv
import googleanalytics
import google.analytics.data
import urllib.parse

# Load the JSON key file
with open('key.json', 'r') as f:
    credentials = json.load(f)

# Create a service account object
service_account = googleanalytics.create_service(credentials)

credentials_dict = {
    "options": {
        "client_email": service_account,
        "private_key": 'private_key'
    }
}
client = google.analytics.data.BetaAnalyticsDataClient(options=credentials_dict)




# Set the view ID
view_id = '74466483'

# Set the date range
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2023-05-01'

# Define the metrics and dimensions
metrics = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:bounce_rate', 'ga:average_time_on_page', 'ga:entrances', 'ga:pageviews', 'ga:unique_pageviews']
dimensions = ['ga:source', 'ga:page']

# Run the report
# Run the report
report = client.reports().generate(
    view_id,
    start_date=start_date,
    end_date=end_date,
    metrics=metrics,
    dimensions=dimensions
).execute()
# Write the report to a CSV file
with open('report.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(report.header)
    for row in report.rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

ERRORS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\CompanyNameCode\CompanyName.py", line 3, in <module>
    import googleanalytics
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\googleanalytics\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import auth, commands, utils, account, auth, blueprint, columns, errors, query, segments
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\googleanalytics\auth\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import oauth
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\googleanalytics\auth\oauth.py", line 7, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "C:\Users\MYNAMEn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 32, in <module>
    import urlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'
```

I've tried pip install of many many packages, I have updated python and all packages too.

Question:
Does anyone have any suggestions? The import urllib.parse is greyed out in VSCode, so its not even being directly used. This makes me believe this has more to do with packages not being called correctly or versions not working together as they should. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) !

I Know that urlparse is for python 2 (i have python 3 and fully updated packages for everything else too), so I'm really lost. The error also appears when I don't include import urllib.parse (mostly because VSCode says its not even needed for the file to compile like I mentioned above).

context: getting specific metrics and dimensions from google analytics 3, saving it as SVG. WIll import SVG to BigQuery, then backfill GA4 with BigQuery data. This deals with eveytrthing up to saving it as a SVG.

I've tried importing a whole bunch of stuff, updating packages, deleting python and all packages, reinstalling that. So so lost :(

Answer (score 0):

For python3, You can use -

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

Please refer to this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).